# using RazorPDF in ASP.Net web forms(outside MVC)

Tags: asp.net, razorpdf

I m not pretty sure whether this is possible but can anyone let me know that how to use RazorPDF to generate PDF in conventional ASP.NET web application(without MVC).

I m able to create PdfResult type object in cs file but my problem is how do I display it in a browser. Also, i have my templates(cshtml) ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding folder structure same as MVC to my existing ASP.net web application and by adding  RazorPDF package component.

I have referred to [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc)